# JWT Token with multiple authentication sources

Tags: asp.net, authentication, jwt, auth0

I have a client application (JS) being provided by a simple ASP.Net Core Website (let's call it 'Website A'). The purpose of 'Website A' is to simply deliver the site. This means, that there is no business logic and it basically could also be a PHP/Rails/Whatever site (it is ASP.Net Core in preparation for OrchardCore being released). The client application (JS) calls my backend api (another ASP.Net Core site - let's call it 'API A') by passing the shared cookie for authentication (so - 'API A' can handle the cookie created by 'Website A'). This means, that ALL business logic is handled through 'API A'. In other words: currently 'Website A' handles authentication (as described in [1]) and the client application (JS) only calls 'API A'). 'Website A' itself does **NOT** do any calls to 'API A' - it is just there for delivering the site.
I want to transform this behaviour into a pure JWT-based authentication. Authentication would be handled through my client application - so 'Website A' basically would not create a cookie anymore.

Currently users on my site can log in through Auth0. The authentication data is stored in a cookie (as described in [1]). My problem is: the backend should always be called with a valid JWT - but I do not require a login (as this is optional). The api exposes a resource, which has a mobile number connected with. This leads to two authentication options:

- A guest is trying to access this resource. A verification code is sent to the mobile number attached to the resource. After submitting the valid verification code, the guest is allowed to access the resource. From this moment on the authentication context is kept throughout the session - unless the user tries to access another resource with a different mobile number attached. Let's call this a soft authentication, as a guest from then on is not really a guest but a verified visitor (so to say: a user **WITHOUT** a stored user account).
- A user is already authenticated (by having logged in and thus being authenticated by Auth0). Further this means that there is already a profile stored for this user with his/her mobile number attached to it. Sending a verification code is skipped as the user is allowed to access the resource unless the user mobile number does not match the resource mobile number. Let's call this a hard authentication, as it is a user **WITH** a stored user account.

So - a visitor may have a JWT issued by Auth0 or... well - or what? A JWT issued by me? My API ('API A') should validate the Auth0 token as described in [2]

What would be an optimal approach to access my API ('API A') with a JWT being either based on a soft authentication or a hard authentication.

---

*Explanation on the terms 'Website A' and 'API A'*

*At a later stage there may be multiple websites (in terms of branded sites) which all should use the same backend API. So there may be a 'Website A' delivering 'Brand A' and a 'Website B' delivering 'Brand B'.
In a preparation for a split into microservices 'API A' might later be a bunch of APIs - 'API A', 'API B',...*

---

[1] https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/aspnet-core/01-login

[2] https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/aspnet-core-webapi

Answer (score 0):

> Currently users on my site can log in through Auth0. The authentication data is stored in a cookie (as described in [1]). My problem is: the backend should always be called with a valid JWT

*Assuming* I understood, you can think of App A *authorization* to access App B (backend api) as *separate* from *user* level *authentication* (aka login).

- User authentication doesn't change. Login is accomplished just as you have it.
- You can then define how your App A will make backend requests to App B separately.

Essentially, cutting things up into 2 different scopes.

1. The latter (backend app) just ensures that it will only process requests from *authorized client apps* (App A or any other that can create a valid JWT your App B requires).
2. App A handles user *authentication*, and decides "when/how" to call your App B by fulfilling some authorization scheme, in this case sending a JWT with its request.

Hth

Comment: Hi - I edited my initial post with some more explanation. I did not mean an App-to-App authorization, but some sort of authorization also for guests

Comment: @identify Unsure what changes. App A is the "front end" app that does _user authentciation_. It determines whether or not to call App B (api) based on that, and for what function(s). The communication between App A and B is locked down with JWT (the only app to app). Essentially App A is the only "public" resource. The existence of App B isn't necessarily "visible"/only known to App A

Answer (score 0):

To summarise, I think your uncertainty is how to handle "guests" (ie. users of App A - ASP.Net Core Website in regards to making calls to an API B (and please be clear on the terminology - here you are talking about an API, not an app - from the point of view of App A.

Further, you are using Auth0 as your Identity Provider (IDP) for authentication with App A. It currently issues an authenticated user both a (JWT) ID Token, and an Access Token to call the API (plus optionally a refresh token if you request with `offline_access` scope.  But the challenge is that your "guest" users (ie. unauthenticated) don't have a JWT Access token.

The following may suit your needs. Set up an API in the Auth0 Dashboard (aka. Resource API) - https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/grant/authorization-code

Also, since you are using ASP .NET Core - and your server-side app is considered a "Confidential Client" - it can store a Client Secret. So it would be appropriate to create Non-Interactive Client - https://auth0.com/docs/clients/client-settings/non-interactive and register this with your (newly created ?) Resource API.  Now, for guests, you can go ahead and use your non-interactive client to obtain a JWT Access token for the secured API B endpoint, and use that when calling the API. Depending on your needs, you can ensure the Guest JWT Access Token returns only the "scopes" appropriate to a Guest account.  Authenticated user JWT Tokens may contain additional scopes if they have privileged access over and above a guest account.

Comment: Hi - I edited my initial posts with some more explanation. I will have a look at the non-interactive client stuff. But I fear, that is does not fit my needs here, as I need a JWT to authenticate my guest in my API to only allow access to the resources attached to his mobile number.